# Every algebraic extension of a finite field $F$ is separable

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, separable-extension

Question: I want to show that every algebraic extension of a finite field $F$ is separable.

Thoughts: I think I know how to do this: let $F\subseteq E$ be an algebraic extension of $F$.  Let $a\in E$.  Then there is some $f(x)\in F[x]$ irreducible such that $f(a)=0$.  So, $f(x)=c_nx^n+\dots +c_1x+c_0$ where $c_i\in F$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $c_n\neq0$.  So, $f'(x)=nc_nx^{n-1}+\dots +c_1$.  Then we consider if $f'(x)=0$ then $(f(x),f'(x))=1$ so $f(x)$ is serpable, and if $f'(x)\neq0$ then I'm going through and eventually getting a contradiction to $f(x)$ being irreducible, thus finishing my proof.  However, it takes about a half of a page to get that contradiction and I was wondering if there was maybe a shorter, or less computational, way of proving this.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Or maybe [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2186685/every-finite-field-is-perfect) answers your question?

Comment: @KReiser maybe I'm over thinking this, and my thought is wrong, but can you have an infinite algebraic extension of a finite field?

Comment: @User7238 An algebraic extension is a compositum of finite extensions.

Comment: It suffices to check that each element $e\in E$ has separable minimal polynomial over $F$. But then $F\subset F(e)$ is a finite extension, and the linked duplicate applies. (You are of course right that there are infinite algebraic extensions of a finite field: the algebraic closure is one, for instance.)